# Bug in JavaScript String.replace() with replace string "$'"?

Tags: javascript

Try the following code in Chrome Web Inspector:

```
> "foo".replace("foo", "$'"); // dollar sign followed by single quote
< "" // wtf
```

Comment: `$' Inserts the portion of the string that follows the matched substring` , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `$$` as `$` is used for referencing groups

```js
var replaced = "foo".replace("foo", "$$'");

snippet.log(replaced);
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter)

> $$    Inserts a "$".

Comment: Awesome, thanks Arun! I didn't know $ was a special character. I'll check the Mozilla spec next time.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative I'm using now is

```
"foo".split("foo").join("$'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems good, $ symbol should contain numeric or integer or floating value,Ex.$120'...

```
var res = str.replace("foo", "$1000'");
```

Answer (score 0):

The explanations above are somewhat incomplete.

The second argument of `string.replace` is a replacer function. When you supply a string as the second argument, it is passed to the default replacement function which interprets the string and replaces `$` with the matched substring. It also replaces `$1`, `$2` etc with any captures you may have defined in the match expression.

In OP's case he doesn't want the default replacer. He wants a replacer function that simply returns the string:

```js
() => "leave my $ alone";
```

Thus, this code

```js
console.log("replace foo with dollar".replace("foo", () => "$"));
```

will return

```
replace $ with dollar
```